# Generate UML Class Diagram for one project in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I want to ask How can I generate UML Class Diagram for only one project in solution ? When I generate by click Architecture -> Generate Dependency Diagram, I get diagram of solution, I have 8 projects in solution, so diagram looks terible. 
I programming in c# and use VS 2010 Ulimate
Can I generate diagram only for some classes ? for example for classes in one folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know this tool but did you try to drag and drop manually the class you want to display into an empty class diagram ? It usually works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN subscription, you can install the Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2, so that you can do this: [How to: Create UML Class Diagrams from Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx).